# AWS ECR trying to use Get-ECRLoginCommnad fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I am new to AWS and I am trying to register an image on ECR on windows. To do that I am using PowerShell to connect to AWS.

Below is my version

```
PS C:\> aws --version

aws-cli/2.0.0 Python/3.7.5 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev4
```

I used aws configure command to login. I went to users -> createdUser -> Security Credentials for Access key and Secret key.

When I use `Get-ECRLoginCommand`

```
PS C:\> Get-ECRLoginCommand

Get-ECRLoginCommand : The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS
Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ECRLoginCommand
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...inCommandCmdlet:GetECRLoginCommandCmdlet) [Get-ECRL
   oginCommand], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.ECR.AmazonECRException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ECR.GetECRLoginCommandCmdlet
```

Can someone please help me how to registry docker image on ECR?

Comment: check the `config` file under  - `%userprofile%/.aws`. make sure the Access key and Secret key are the same as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Access Id and Secret key %userprofile%/.aws is matching.
`aws ecr list-images --repository-name testrepo` is returning empty list so I assume I am able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

Even on Windows,

it's easier to use push instructions on Linux and macOS.

you just need to install AWS CLI, docker, and set up AWS credentials.

Install AWS CLI version 2

```
msiexec.exe /i https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi
```

To confirm the installation

```
C:\> aws --version
aws-cli/2.2.43 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
```

In AWS IAM, create user with the required role.

It's not recommended. I simply created a user with AdministratorAccess.

set up your AWS credentials

```
aws configure

AWS Access Key ID [None]: Access Key
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: Secret Key
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

Now, Authenticate the docker of the Amazon ECR registry

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin YOUR-REGISTRY-URL

Login Succeeded
```

Finally, Pushing a Docker Image

```
docker build -t YOUR-BUILD-NAME .
docker tag YOUR-BUILD-NAME:latest YOUR-REGISTRY-URL/YOUR-BUILD-NAME:latest
docker push YOUR-REGISTRY-URL/YOUR-BUILD-NAME:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling `AWS CLI V2` and install `AWS CLI V1` that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first **set up you aws credentials** on your Windows PC.

Separately you need to set up it for aws cli and aws sdk:

from documentation:

> Credentials Store Locations
> The AWS Tools for PowerShell can use either of two credentials stores:
>
> The AWS SDK store, which encrypts your credentials and stores them in your home folder. > In Windows, this store is located at:  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit\RegisteredAccounts.json.
>
> The AWS SDK for .NET and Toolkit for Visual Studio can also use the AWS SDK store.
>
> The shared credentials file, which is also located in your home folder, but stores credentials as plain text.
>
> By default, the credentials file is stored here:
>
> On Windows: C:\Users\username.aws\credentials
>
> On Mac/Linux: ~/.aws/credentials
>
> The AWS SDKs and the AWS Command Line Interface can also use the credentials file. If you're running a script outside of your AWS user context, be sure that the file that contains your credentials is copied to a location where all user accounts (local system and user) can access your credentials.

**Example:**

```
PS > Set-AWSCredential `
                 -AccessKey AKIA0123456787EXAMPLE `
                 -SecretKey wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY `
                 -StoreAs MyNewProfile
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html#specifying-your-aws-credentials-store

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Get-AWSCredential -ListProfileDetail
```

If you get something like this(**2 defaults**)

[image]

The 1st default is causing the issue! you should remove it with the following command

```
Remove-AWSCredentialProfile -ProfileName default
```

Once you only have a single default left(the working one) *Get-ECRLoginCommand* should work as expected.